# Find and replace variables names in a python script programmatically

Tags: python, regex, abstract-syntax-tree

I am parsing my script.py using the `ast` module.
I have found all the variable names in the text by:

```
import ast
python_code= open('D:\\script.py', 'r').read()
root = ast.parse(python_code)
names = sorted({node.id for node in ast.walk(root) if isinstance(node, ast.Name)})
```

then I would like to find and replace each of occurrence of each of the names with a string from another list.

```
names = ['var', 'bar',...]
names_edit=['var1','ba1r',...]
```

So far, I have been able to replace each variable by a atring:

```
 import re
 line = re.sub('\w+(?=\()', 'SUBSTRING', python_code)
```

How do I replace all the occurrences of one variable instead?
The ultimate goal is to obfuscate python source code files...

Comment: Python code obfuscation is a solved problem. Why don't you take an existing library?

Comment: hints? A custom implementation is possibly safer?

Comment: You have to basically track the scope of the variable and then build the replacement table/scope tree, if you wish to tackle this.